# Thousands of identical self-signed intermediate certificates. What's creating them?

Tags: windows-7, windows, certificate

This is on Windows 7 Professional SP1.

The internet was very slow, and inspecting page loads showed the TLS handshake  taking upwards of 30 seconds.

Looking at the Windows certificate store, there are a few extra intermediate certificates:
[image: Screenshot of certificate manager]
[image: Screenshot of certificate General tab]
[image: Screenshot of certificate Details tab]
[image: Screenshot of certificate Certification Path tab]

`DiningRoom` is the name of the computer. These self-signed certificates are untrusted, and are not part of any certificate chain.

Currently, there are a total of 395 of these self-signed certificates, and 1-3 new ones being created each day.

When I originally looked into this problem, there were 2,000+, and I deleted them. However, they keep coming back.

They don't appear to be correlated to computer boots.

I don't see any security event logs for events 1001-1006, 4884, 4887.

How can I determine what is creating these certificates?

**Network Details**
Computer is named DiningRoom, and is connected directly to the router (D-Link DIR-605L) via ethernet. It is a home network, and IP address is reserved DHCP set up on router.

Comment: Is your PC named "dining room"? Is it part of a network in your place? We need detailed information about your network please.

Comment: @Moab I've edited network details into the question, please let me know if there is more information I should add.

Comment: You can check the Event viewer for application and service log `Microsoft/Windows/CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-User/Operational`.

Comment: @Robert That particular log folder doesn't exist, only `CertificateServicesClient-CredentialRoaming`, and it was disabled. I have enabled it in the meantime.

Comment: Sorry, missed that you are talking about an obsolete and totally insecure Windows version (you are still using SP1!?). The log is available on Windows 10.

Comment: Is there a CA named "Dining Room" under Trusted Roots as well? (Does its 'Properties' page reveal any more information?) Are you using any kind of third-party antivirus software with "web protection", or parental control software? Do these "Dining Room" certificates show up in TLS handshakes?

Comment: @user1686 Edited to add screenshots of cert details. There are no DiningRoom certificates in root certs, or in any other cert store, and they are not part of the cert chain in TLS handshakes (or at least not on Google or SuperUser).

The only third-party software is SpyBot, which I have disabled for now to see if it is the cause. The router has parental controls, but they are disabled.